# Use ORDER BY on String Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

All I have the following table that I am needing to **order by** depending on the time it starts.

Example data:

```
4:30pm-10:00pm
5:00am-4:00pm
10:30am-4:00pm
2:00pm-10:45pm
5:00am-3:00pm|3:30pm-10:00pm
NA
7:30am-3:30pm
10:00am-3:30pm
7:31am-1:01pm
2:00pm-10:00pm
```

So in the example string times above, I would need it to order them like so:

```
5:00am-3:00pm
5:00am-4:00pm
7:30am-3:30pm
7:31am-1:01pm
10:00am-3:30pm
10:30am-4:00pm
2:00pm-10:00pm
2:00pm-10:45pm
3:30pm-10:00pm
4:30pm-10:00pm
```

Currently I am getting the following when running this query:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[mon]
FROM [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
ORDER BY mon DESC
```

And the output is:

```
id  mon
9   7:31am-1:01pm
7   7:30am-3:30pm
2   5:00am-4:00pm
5   5:00am-3:00pm
1   4:30pm-10:00pm
6   3:30pm-10:00pm
4   2:00pm-10:45pm
10  2:00pm-10:00pm
3   10:30am-4:00pm
8   10:00am-3:30pm
```

Comment: Since those are **strings**, the `ORDER BY` goes by strings, and returns the **correct result** for that use case. If you need it ordered by **time**, you need to provide a value of type `TIME` :.... (e.g. you need to extract the *start time* from that string and order by that)

Comment: The root of the issue is that you have used the incorrect data type. In future consider using a pair of `time` or `datetime` columns. In the meantime you need to convert what you have to something useful on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like below,

```
SELECT [id],
       [mon]
FROM   [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
ORDER BY
       CAST(LEFT(mon, CHARINDEX('-', mon) -1) AS TIME),
       CAST(RIGHT(mon,LEN(mon)-(CHARINDEX('-',mon))) AS TIME)
```

*Cast is ANSI and ANSI-SQL is more portable across database platforms*
*So I have used Cast over here and yest it will work as per your expected output!*

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FVB8418)**</kbd>

***[Updated Answer](http://rextester.com/XOJTMZ18136)***

```
SELECT [id],
       [mon]
FROM   [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
ORDER BY
       CAST(LEFT(NULLIF(mon,'NA'), CHARINDEX('-', NULLIF(mon,'NA')) -1) AS TIME),
       CAST(RIGHT(NULLIF(mon,'NA'),LEN(NULLIF(mon,'NA'))-(CHARINDEX('-',NULLIF(mon,'NA')))) AS TIME)
```

<kbd>**[`New Updated Answer`](http://rextester.com/DOL20069)**</kbd>

This could be the solution.

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT [id],
       [mon]
FROM   [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
WHERE  [mon] NOT LIKE '%|%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT [id],
       LEFT(
           LEFT(mon, LEN(mon) -CHARINDEX('|', mon)),
           LEN(LEFT(mon, LEN(mon) -CHARINDEX('|', mon))) -1
       ) [mon]
FROM   [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
WHERE  [mon] LIKE '%|%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT [id],
       RIGHT(mon, LEN(mon) -CHARINDEX('|', mon)) [mon]
FROM   [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
WHERE  [mon] LIKE '%|%' )

SELECT id,[mon] FROM cte 
order by CAST(LEFT(NULLIF(mon,'NA'), CHARINDEX('-', NULLIF(mon,'NA')) -1) AS TIME),
       CAST(RIGHT(NULLIF(mon,'NA'),LEN(NULLIF(mon,'NA'))-(CHARINDEX('-',NULLIF(mon,'NA')))) AS TIME)
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks pedram!

Comment: Actually I forgot to say that some of the time data is formatted like NA if it has no time related. How would I compensate for that?

Comment: you can use NULLIF - if the data formatted like NA . See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but how would you check for the value **5:00am-3:00pm|3:30pm-10:00pm**? I would just be interested in the first time regardless.

Comment: Please check updated answer link. Also yes if you want to use convert you can convert instead of cast. let me know if you need further help. thanks

Comment: AWESOME! However, I am looking to just *not* see that second time value. I just want to focus on the first time and only that.

Comment: then you can make changes in my made SQL Query right? Let me know if you need help in that also!!

Comment: Would using **CAST(LEFT(mon, CHARINDEX('-', mon) -1) AS TIME)** get all that I needed?

Comment: Thanks for the help again, pedram.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    [id],[mon]
FROM 
    [DBc83].[dbo].[tmpTable]
ORDER BY 
    convert(time, substring(mon,0,charindex('-',mon))), 
    convert(time, substring(mon,charindex('-',mon)+1,len(mon)))
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to say that some of the time data is formatted like NA if it has no time related. How would I compensate for that?